# When importing excel into pandas or dask.dataframe spaces are being replaced by '_x0200_' and other special characters by similar codes

Tags: python, pandas, import, dask

I am trying to import a csv file into python using pandas or dask.dataframe and im getting the error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 6892: character maps to \<undefined\>", if i import the excel file (xlsx format) instead all spaces are being replaced by '_x0020_'.
```

Below are all my attempts:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

import pandas as pd

import os

os.chdir(...)
names_csv = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv' , encoding = 'cp1252')
names_csv_dd = dd.read_csv('file_name.csv' , encoding = 'cp1252')

names_excel = pd.read_excel("file_name.xlsx")

parts = dask.delayed(pd.read_excel("file_name.xlsx"))

df = dd.from_delayed(parts)
```

Comment: Is the file a text csv (i.e. raw ASCII text) or an excel file? If it is an excel file, what is the encoding it is saved with?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using `pd.read_excel()` and solved it by changing the encoding in Excel to Unicode (utf-8).

I followed [these steps](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/choose-text-encoding-when-you-open-and-save-files-60d59c21-88b5-4006-831c-d536d42fd861).

Comment: While that link may answer the question, you should also include the essential parts into the answer itself. Link-only answers usually get deleted. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33739627)